# Relationship between FluentValidation Framework and Clean Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation, clean-architecture

In the clean architecture we don't create any dependency in application layer but every instructor use fluentValidation in that layer, isn't that a dependency ?

Comment: AFAIK FluentValidation is used for mediator requests.. It is dependency as any request. Its registered via some generic mechanism. Why shouldnt we create dependencies in Application Layer?

Comment: I don't know every explanation that I ever saw say that, all dependency is gonna be in the infrastructure layer, in application layer we just build our interfaces then we use FluentValidation framework in application layer then I confused.

Comment: Yes, it is a dependency but Clean Architecture must not be strictly applied, otherwise you are complicating your life. You have to be pragmatic instead of dogmatic.

Answer (score 0):

An app layer's interfaces should avoid dependencies leaking outside the layer.  For `FluentValidation` in particular:

```
ValidationResult DoSomething(Thing thing);
```

`ValidationResult` is a class defined by FluentValidation, and since FluentValidation is a dependency *for that app layer* the return of a `ValidationResult` is leaking FluentValidation to another layer.

Instead, the app layer that is using FluentValidation should define its own result which extends no other external dependency.  For example:

```
public class ApiResult // no extension of any other external dependency
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Errors {get; protected set;}
}
```

so the interface to the app layer would be changed to:

```
ApiResult DoSomething(Thing thing);
```

and internally, the app layer can use FluentValidation and map the results from   FluentValidation's `ValidationResult` to `ApiResult`.

Comment: I guess, either my english or my software knowledge is not enough because I didn't understand you. I still wondering what are the fluentValidation framework doing in app layer.

Answer (score 0):

When taking Clean Architecture strict we would have to conclude that such a dependency breaks the Dependency Rule.

On the other hand: "some dependencies we have to marry" as Uncle Bob writes. For example: if you develop based on .NET you also marry the libraries of that framework/platform.

In the end it is a tradeoff decision which has to be taken conscious: what do you value more, the benefit of the independence from any/most third party library in your application layer or the benefit of reusing functionalities others created and maintain.

Comment: Actually my knowledge about the application layer is it has a dependency just with domain layer that's why I guess the first one I value more in that architecture.

Comment: And also I understood from your answer if we use .net libraries (like FluentValidation which is for .Net) that doesn't meant we have dependency; right ?

Comment: As FluentValidation is not directly part of .NET it should be considered as third party library and so as external dependency. But is still up to you to decided whether you consider this dependency as a problem because you make your core application logic dependent on it or whether you value the code reuse more

Comment: Of Course I don't value to reuse more code but application layer logic is not like that it needs to be independent.